# ASP.NET Core authentication and authorization with OIDC without creating local copies of the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I've just created a new ASP.NET Core application using Visual Studio, it has the authentication type set to "Individual Accounts":

[image]

I've added some code to handle OIDC:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(openIdOptions =>
{
    openIdOptions.ClientId = "myClientId";
    openIdOptions.Authority = "myAuthority";
    openIdOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    openIdOptions.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
    openIdOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    openIdOptions.SaveTokens = true;
```

Which is all well and good, I can click to login with OpenIdConnect:

[image: openId connect login]

When I log in with the provided credentials it pops up asking me to Associate my OpenIdConnect account:

[image]

I don't want to have to do this. Retrieving the access token and id token is sufficient for what I want to do, I don't require a local copy of the user. Being new to ASP.net and having not used Razor before it's not immediately obvious what code I should delete — if that's even the correct approach. I've played around with deleting various bits such as the Db setup as I don't really require it, although I suspect Razor does in some regard.

The `Program.cs` looks as follows:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    {
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(openIdOptions =>
{
    openIdOptions.ClientId = "clientId";
    openIdOptions.Authority = "authority";
    openIdOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    openIdOptions.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
    openIdOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    openIdOptions.SaveTokens = true;
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"); });

app.Run();
```

Comment: Its not that razor requires certain things, the asp user functionality built into .net requires a certain structure. Without it you will run into issues. Don't focus on removing something because you "don't need it". In the end of the day the extra information returned matters very little. It is not a significant amount of work for the computer. I recommend looking at IdentityServer4.